# checkbox inside a gridview within updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, autopostback

I have a `gridview` with a `checkbox` in first column. I set `checkbox` property of `autopostback="true"`. The `gridview` is inside the `updatepanel`. When `checkbox` is `checked` i want to make one `panel` as visible, which panel is outside the update panel. I check the code with check point, which is go through the code, but its not working. Can any one help me?..

Thanks in advance.

My code is here for your reference...

HTML Code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="ploperation" runat="server" CssClass="plop" Visible="False">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnasspam" runat="server" CssClass="panelbtn" Font-Names="Calibri"
                    Font-Size="14px" Font-Underline="False" OnClick="lbtnasspam_Click">Report As Spam</asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Panel>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:GridView ID="gvmail" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

              <Columns>
                  <asp:TemplateField>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:CheckBox ID="chkchild" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkchild_CheckedChanged"/>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                      <ItemStyle Width="15px" />
                  </asp:TemplateField>
              </Columns>         
         </asp:GridView>
     </ContentTemplate>                        
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C# Code:

```
protected void chkchild_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ploperation.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: update panel do partial page loading....so if u wana show ur panel than include it also in ur update panel.

Comment: @AmitSingh Thanks.. its works with in update panel...

Comment: @AmitSingh Is it possible to make this outside of update panel?

Comment: no freind it is not unless u use ajax or do normal page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update panel does partial page loading....
[check link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

so if you want to show your panel than include it also in your update panel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [initializeRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397460.aspx) - this event is raised when an asynchronous post back occurs(When you check the checkbox in your gridview it initiates an async postback because it's inside an update panel).

Just change ploperation to a div instead of `<asp:Panel` and you can use javascript to show/hide it:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_initializeRequest(initializeRequest);

    function initializeRequest(sender, args) {
        document.getElementById('ploperation').style.display = 'block';
    }

</script>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvmail" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkchild" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="15px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<div id="ploperation" style="display:none;" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnasspam" runat="server" CssClass="panelbtn" Font-Names="Calibri"
        Font-Size="14px" Font-Underline="False" OnClick="lbtnasspam_Click">Report As Spam</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
</form>
```

Alternatively you can stick to the way you've done it, just place `<asp:Panel` inside UpdatePanel -> ContentTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Put the UpdatePanel on the control you want to change, not on the GridView. Do not forget to Reference the GridView on the Triggers section. For example, if you want to change a label text use the following code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" />
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvmail"  />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:GridView ID="gvmail" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkchild" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkchild_CheckedChanged"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="15px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>         
</asp:GridView>
```